# React emit KeyboardEvent from input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Is there a way to emit KeyboardEvent for input in React ?

I tried with:

```
this.input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key: 'Backspace',
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false
}));
this.input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
    key: 'Backspace',
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false
}));
this.input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
    key: 'Backspace',
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false
}));
```

But none of this triggers any handler (`onKeyDown`, `onKeyPress`, `onKeyUp`).

Handlers are called on manually key press only ...

Comment: keyboards events are already emitted by react , you just have to attach the appropriate handler function to the required event
eg: <input onKeyDown={this.handleKeydown}/>

refer [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)

Comment: Your code works for me. I have a feeling the problem is your input reference. How are you setting `this.input`? And when are you making these dispatchEvent calls?

Comment: @AquibVadsaria I want to emit them not listen for them.

Comment: @Shawn I was calling `dispatchEvent` in `onKeyDown` handler and I wanted to make a recursive event loop but turn out this was possible only when events are dispatched on `window` so I've re-think how the component should work and instead of recursive event loop I've just `preventDefault` when I needed `Backspace` emit. Any way the living standart prevents defualt action on `untrust`ed `event`s so the whole `Backspace` idea is not possible and in high performance cost.